# Scatter plot with string X and Y coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scatter

I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22095746/scatter-plots-with-string-arrays-in-matplotlib), but I was wondering if there is a way to do it without pandas.

This is what I have tried.
`X_AXIS`, and `Y_AXIS` are strings that are contained in `xTickMarks` and `yTickMarks`, respectively.

Each value in `X_AXIS` and `Y_AXIS` has a corresponding `Z_AXIS` value..and the the size of the scatter point is represented using the list `FREQ`.

```
xTickMarks = ["0B", "1B", "2B", "1B3S", "2B2S"]
yTickMarks = ["-1S","0S", "1S", "2S", "3S", "4S"]
matplotlib.rc('font', serif='Helvetica Neue')
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex='false')
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 10})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11.69,4.88)) # for landscape
axes1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

'''
Tuple of big,small cores with a tuple of power.
let x be big core
let y be small core
let z be Power
'''

plt.grid(True,linestyle='-',color='0.75')
x = X_AXIS
y = Y_AXIS
z = Z_AXIS
s = [int(FREQ[i])/1000000.0 for i in range(len(FREQ))]

plt.scatter(x,y,s=s,c=z, marker = 'o', cmap = cm.jet )
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label('Frequency', fontsize=20)

xtickNames = axes1.set_xticklabels(xTickMarks)
ytickNames = axes1.set_yticklabels(yTickMarks)
axes1.set_ylabel('Small cores')
axes1.set_xlabel('Big cores')
axes1.legend(prop={'size':5}, ncol=4)
axes1.xaxis.grid(True)
figsize=(11.69,8.27) # for landscape
fig.savefig(savepath + 'state-transition.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300, pad_inches=0.1)
plt.clf()
```

When I run this, `plt.scatter` expects a floating point value and not a string.

I want to do it without `pandas`.

Sample values of X_AXIS, Y_AXIS and Z_AXIS:

```
X_AXIS = ['1B', '2B', '2B', '2B']
Y_AXIS = ['0S', '0S', '2S', '2S']
Z_AXIS = [1.5637257394958113, 1.5399805470086181, 1.4030363999998978, 1.4198133749999822]
```

Comment: please add a sample of X_AXIS, Y_AXIS and Z_AXIS values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need numbers for the scatter plot. You can map your string values to numbers and then set the ticks to match the mapping.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

X_AXIS = ['1B', '2B', '2B', '1B3S']
Y_AXIS = ['0S', '0S', '2S', '2S']
Z_AXIS = [1.5637257394958113, 1.5399805470086181, 1.4030363999998978, 1.4198133749999822]
FREQ = [5000000.] * 4

xTickMarks = ["0B", "1B", "2B", "1B3S", "2B2S"]
yTickMarks = ["-1S","0S", "1S", "2S", "3S", "4S"]

matplotlib.rc('font', serif='Helvetica Neue')
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex='false')
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 10})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11.69,4.88)) # for landscape
axes1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

'''
Tuple of big,small cores with a tuple of power.
let x be big core
let y be small core
let z be Power
'''

plt.grid(True,linestyle='-',color='0.75')
x = [xTickMarks.index(i) for i in X_AXIS]
y = [yTickMarks.index(i) for i in Y_AXIS]
z = Z_AXIS
s = [int(FREQ[i])/1000000.0 for i in range(len(FREQ))]

plt.scatter(x,y,s=s,c=z, marker = 'o', cmap = cm.jet )
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label('Frequency', fontsize=20)

axes1.set_xlim((0, len(xTickMarks)-1))
axes1.set_ylim((0, len(yTickMarks)-1))
axes1.set_xticks(xrange(len(xTickMarks)))
axes1.set_yticks(xrange(len(yTickMarks)))
axes1.set_xticklabels(xTickMarks)
axes1.set_yticklabels(yTickMarks)
axes1.set_ylabel('Small cores')
axes1.set_xlabel('Big cores')
axes1.legend(prop={'size':5}, ncol=4)
axes1.xaxis.grid(True)
figsize=(11.69,8.27) # for landscape
#fig.savefig('state-transition.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300, pad_inches=0.1)
plt.show()
```

What I changed here compared to your code are the values for x and y:

```
x = [xTickMarks.index(i) for i in X_AXIS]
y = [yTickMarks.index(i) for i in Y_AXIS]
```

and the ticks of your axes:

```
axes1.set_xlim((0, len(xTickMarks)-1))
axes1.set_ylim((0, len(yTickMarks)-1))
axes1.set_xticks(xrange(len(xTickMarks)))
axes1.set_yticks(xrange(len(yTickMarks)))
axes1.set_xticklabels(xTickMarks)
axes1.set_yticklabels(yTickMarks)
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're welcome :-) you had the tick labels right but the number of ticks was wrong.