# Python: Extract the key and value from a groupby statement in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have this movie dataframe, i would like to group it so that i get the gerne that appears most in each year:

```
data = {'year' : [2000,2000,2001,2001, 2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2002], 'movie': ['movie1','movie2', 'movie3', 'movie4', 'movie5', 'movie6', 'movie7', 'movie8', 'movie9', 'movie10'], 'genre': ['action', 'action', 'comedy', 'drama','comedy', 'horror', 'sci-fi','horror', 'horror', 'action']}
movie = pd.DataFrame(data)
movie
```

```
desired result should look like:
2000 : action 
2001 : comedy
2002 : horror
```

I tried the following:

```
movie.groupby(["year", "genre"])['genre'].value_counts().max(level = 0)
```

i get from that something like:
2
2
3

Answer (score 2):

you can use **Series.mode**:

```
dfx=movie.groupby(['year'])['genre'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
print(dfx)
'''
year    genre
2000    action
2001    comedy
2002    horror

'''
print(type(movie.groupby(['year'])['genre']))
'''
<class 'pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy'>
'''
```

Comment: Hi Clegane, so the .mode is a method for a pd.Series ? and it returns the most frequent value in that series .. but what does agg() do ?

Comment: check [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html) also, in your case the **agg** function answers the question of what to do for each group (sum, count, mean, mode eg.)

Comment: thank you, it worked as expected, i would like to ask if this outcome is plottable ? and which plot is more suited ?

Comment: maybe scatter plot. An [example:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47408138/15415267)